# Position of numpy random seed

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have the following code for running an autoregressive process:

```
import numpy as np



 def AR1(mu,phi,x0, Nt, a, b, neg = False):


    AR_1 = []

    x1 = np.zeros(len(x0))

    #np.random.seed(0)


    for j in range(Nt):
        #np.random.seed(0)
        for i in range(len(x0)):   
            x1[i] = mu[i] + phi*(x0[i] - mu[i]) + ss.truncnorm.rvs(a[i],b[i])  

        AR_1.append(x1)
        x0 = x1.copy()
        x1 = np.zeros(len(x0))

    return AR_1
```

As you can see I have a couple of positions where I might put `np.random.seed(0)`. I want the same set of random numbers to be chosen for every run so that I can see the effect of varying phi. With this in mind, where should i place `np.random.seed` in the code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's best to [pass it to `rvs()` as the `random_state` keyword argument](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous.rvs).

Comment: I tried this but it chose the same number every time, which is not what I'm wanting here. I want the same set of random numbers to be chosen each time I run the AR1 process over the same number of lags, if that makes sense?

Comment: Just use a list of deterministic seeds then.

Comment: Is this the only way to do it or could it be implemented into the code (I plan to extend the code to consider when x1 is negative and if so redo the x1 calculation until its value is positive)

Comment: I am not sure I understand... Can you please amend the questions with code that does this?